# Timezone conversions incorrect in Rails when using Time.zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Time.zone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
Time.zone 
=> (GMT+05:30) Asia/Kolkata
```

Time.zone has been set properly.

```
Time.zone.parse('0000-01-01 03:00:00 UTC').strftime('%l:%M %p')
=> " 8:53 AM"
```

Incorrect offset being applied (+05:33 vs +05:30)

Why does this happen? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The time zone in Calcutta before 1941](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=54&year=1941) seems to have been 5 hours, 53 minutes ahead of UTC.

If you use a year later than that (for example year 2000) instead of year 0, you should get the result you expect.

Due to daylight savings time, you can't really convert a UTC time to a local time, 8:00UTC can convert to different local times in summer and winter. For automatic conversion to give the correct result, you need a full date, not just a time.